# Normalizing directional derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields

Let we are in a flat 2D space, and we have 3 vector fields:
$u = x e_y$,
$v = e_x + 2 e_y$,
$w = 2 e_x + 4 e_y$.
Now if we calculate directional derivative of u in the direction of v we get $\partial_x (x e_y) + 2 \partial _y(0e_y) = e_y$. However, directional derivative in the direction of w gets us $2e_y$.
Why are the directional derivatives different? w is just an scaled version of v, the direction is the same. Shouldn’t the results be normalised?

Comment: $v$ and $w$ are constant vector fields then have zero vector as derivative

Comment: u is not constant. $v(u) = v^i \partial_i (u^j e_j)$

Comment: What exactly is the definition of directional derivative you're applying here?

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that for any two vector fields $X$ and $Y$ and a non zero constant $c$ we should have $XY=X(cY)$? That's clearly incorrect since the vectors $e_{x_i}$, are derivations, which are linear.